# Silverlight - Embedded font fails to load... sometimes

Tags: silverlight

I have Silverlight application that is using an embedded font. The font works as expected 98% of the time. However, some of the time the font never loads. I don't get any errors, it just renders all text in a fall back font. Has anyone else run into this? Any ideas on what could be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Assuming you have the font file set as a 'Resource' and 'Do not copy option' under build options. Here is what fixed it in my project.

When the font file was referenced directly, it would work about 75% of the time...

**FontFamily="./Folder/FontFile.TTF#Font Name"**

For class libraries the syntax is different, once I switched to using this syntax the font always loaded.

**FontFamily="AssembyName;component/Folder/FontFile.TTF#Font Name"**

In my project, if you select the font using in the property settings for the control using Visual Studio, it defaulted to option 1, which was unreliable.

Comment: Are you saying you are using the class library syntax even though the font is actually in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes, just substitute AssemblyName with your project namespace.